# How much money do I need to show as proof of support when applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, proof-of-funds

I am an Indian citizen studying in Italy on an Italian visa that expires 19 November, 2015. I have *permesso di soggiorno*. I want to visit the United Kingdom for my vacations for a week during March. I know the procedures already, however I am a little bit confused about the amount that I must show as a proof of support with my bank statements. I will stay for a week with my friends who are also students in Italy and will be in London for 5 days. What would be the amount in Euros that I need to show for my visit to UK?

Answer (score 12):

There is no fixed amount of cash specified for a UK visa.  The rules state...

> will maintain and accommodate himself and any dependants adequately
>   out of resources available to him without recourse to public funds or
>   taking employment; or will, with any dependants, be maintained and/or
>   accommodated adequately by relatives or friends who can demonstrate
>   they are able and intend to do so, and are legally present in the
>   United Kingdom, or will be at the time of their visit; and

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/381797/Immigration_Rules_-_Part_2_final.pdf

They are more interested in assurances that the evidence you present clearly shows that the money is yours to use freely for your trip and that you will not become destitute.  They will also be interested in assurances that the money is appropriate for a genuine tourist agenda in central London.

Having said that, many people use a rule of thumb of (for example) GBP 80 - 120 per day in excess of accommodation, but this is strictly a subjective measure.  If your per diem falls too low, they will not believe you are a genuine tourist.

Finally, if they see that you are committing an amount that is out-of-whack with your earnings and lifestyle, they will get worried.  So if you show funds equivalent to, for example, six months of earnings, your application will be imperilled.

Based upon what you wrote, you have free accommodation.  It's wise to document this well so that you can exclude those funds.

## Update 12 June 2015

The visitor rules are now at [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423477/20150424_mmigration_rules_app_v_final_v2.pdf)

Same rule as before except that they have tightened up the co-sponsor requirements.

---

See also the canonical at: [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)