# Inviting parents immediately after you land UK first time

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I will be travelling to UK next week and I want to invite my parents. So can I send invitation letter immediately within a week. I will be staying in apartment with three months of agreement.
But somebody told me to send invitation letter you must at least spend three months in UK.
It won't be possible for them to join in winter so they will go back in October

Comment: I'm not familiar with the UK visitor visa process, but I don't think there's anything like an invitation letter for tourism... You could sponsor them, but that would indeed require you to have a job, bank account statements going back at least 3 months, and so on...

Comment: It sounds like the kind of behaviour that would make the authorities consider revoking your visa.

Comment: Also, you haven't stated what status you have in the UK. If you are in the UK on a visitor visa yourself, of course, just forget about it.

Comment: I am on work permit visa.

Comment: Is it require to submit last three months UK bank account?

Comment: Will your parents be paying for their own travel, or depending on you to help them financially? What sort of ties do they have to their home country?

Comment: They will pay for their own travel...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I sponsor my Serbian girlfriend for a 2 week visit on a Standard Visitor visa if I have been with my employer for less than 6 months?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143029/can-i-sponsor-my-serbian-girlfriend-for-a-2-week-visit-on-a-standard-visitor-vis)

Comment: If they have strong ties to their home country (jobs, property, dependent children or parents, etc.) and a good situation, they probably can just apply for a visitor visa without needing anything from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parents can afford to pay for their own travel, it is better for them to present themselves as independent people with a social and economic life in their own country, not your dependents. In that case, there is no need for you to provide any letter. They can apply for visitor visas. They will need a history of bank statements in their home country to show they can afford the travel.

Whether they will be able to get visas depends on the nature and extent of their ties to their home, such as other relatives who are not traveling with them, jobs, property, or a business. The fact that you say they need to return by a specific time is encouraging. Any commitment that limits how long they can stay in the UK is good.

Comment: Is visitor visa duration is also of six month or only valid till the number days they will stay in the UK?

Comment: Regardless of the nominal visa duration, they should make only minor changes to the plan they stated in their applications. See [Cancelled UK visa on entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry).