# Letters from friends? UK holiday visa

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel

I am applying for a holiday visa (I was refused entry in 2018 as a non genuine visitor) and I was advised to get letters from my friends here in the US for my application. With this, I am to get a letter from my school as well. I am wondering what the purpose of doing this is and what should the letters from my friends even say? Disclosure: I do not have many close friends so I am finding this part very challenging.

The documents I was told to get: 
**Letters from friends,
6 months bank info,
OR letter from my school (proof of enrollment)

Is any of this really necessary if I am only visiting for 2 weeks?

Comment: Do you have perhaps teammates, or a teacher who could write a letter? A pastor?

Comment: I have been told letters a useless. The one tie I have is school, that’s pretty much it. Yay me.

Answer (score 6):

No such letters from US friends (or even UK) mean anything to the U.K. authorities. That advice was useless. Don’t bother with it.

Focus on the actual requirements of the application.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. So basically the letters from friends in the US would serve as a tie back? Or so we have been told...I am applying for a holiday visa to visit for two weeks in June and I am not sure what documents to bring to the interview. I don’t have many ties like friends or a job. I was a full time student in 2018-2019 so I have not had an income. Should my boyfriend provide a letter saying he is inviting me to stay?

Comment: @Plumdiggy Assuming you’re a US citizen applying to the UK (your question isn’t entirely clear), letters from friends in the US to prove ties to the US are useless, as Hanky Panky’s answer states.A letter from your boyfriend (in the UK?) is also pretty useless if you can’t prove ties to home eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country Is your boyfriend sponsoring your trip https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143029/can-i-sponsor-my-serbian-girlfriend-for-a-2-week-visit-on-a-standard-visitor-vis/143043?

Comment: I have been in school full time so I don’t have much saved up in terms of traveling to the UK. I’m not sure if I understand sponsoring? I am visiting him and staying with his family. Is this the same? I plan on getting money either working some jobs here and there (uber/babysitting) and whatever my parents are gracious enough to give me. I just don’t have really solid ties to the US. I don’t have a lot of friends, I don’t have sports or things I do aside school. I am planning to visit for 2 weeks with roughly 600$ on me.

Comment: The most I can prove in terms of ties are letters from family, and letter from my school (if I get accepted to university) i also plan to get a letter saying that I have been enrolled full time and that I have been keeping myself busy. I have been told since I have not been working, a letter from my school can be used to as proof I am a full time student.

Comment: @Plumdiggy Confirmation of university enrolment may help, but it might be better if you’d actually commenced your studies